# moving data from neo4j 2.0 M06 to neo4j 2.0 match return no result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been testing neo4j using M01 to M06. I was able to copy the graph.db directory each time when I download a new version into the data directory, and it always seem to run ok. But I just download the GA release of neo4j 2.0. And when I try to run a simple query

"Match (n:Flight) return n limit 25" it return 0 records. 
As a matter of fact. All the Match (n:Label) return n limit 25 always return 0 records.

But the other query seems to be ok (for example if I do "match (n:Flight) where n.fltno=1234 return n limit 25" then it runs fine. Does any one know why this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Between M06 and 2.0 final there is a manual step when upgrading.

Please read: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/11/neo4j-200-rc1-final-preparations.html

And try these manual steps after a backup:

### Caution: manual upgrade between milestones

Data stores created with any previous milestone version can not be used with 2.0.0-RC1 unless a manual upgrade is performed. This is due to incompatible changes made to the store files. Please proceed with caution, backing up your data before attempting to manually upgrade.

Manual upgrade (only from 2.0.0-M06, and after you've backed up):

- Cleanly shut down on the old version on Neo4j 2.0.0-M06

  `$ bin/neo4j stop`
- Navigate to the database directory

  `$ cd data/graph.db`
- Delete the label scan store (this is the critical part that has a new format). It will be recreated on startup.

  `$ rm -rf schema/label`
- Start with the new version of Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1

  `$ bin/neo4j start`